# Get the value of data-* without knowing the specific id

Tags: jquery, html

I have this html with a data tag with the name price.

```js
$('input:radio[name="optradio"]').change(function() {
  var selectedText = $(this).closest('.radio-inline').text();
  var selectedCapacity = $(this).attr('data-capaciteit');
  var selectedPrice = $(this).closest('.bb').attr('data-price');
  console.log('Selected Text ', selectedText);
  console.log('Selected Capacity ', selectedCapacity);
  console.log('Selected Price ', selectedPrice);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='clearfix gbo' id='bike_economy' data-capaciteit='economy bike'>
  <div style='float: left;' class='bb'><img class='tic' src=''></div>
  <div style='float: left;' class='economy'>Economy</div>
  <div style='float: right;' class='infuhr'>
    <ion-icon class='ic' name='information-circle-outline' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='right' title='lorem ipsum'></ion-icon>
  </div>
  <div style='float: right;' class='bb transport_amount'><span class='bb' id='economy_bike_amount' data-price='400'>Ksh 250</span>
    <br/> <span class='pt' id='economy_bike_pt'>Pickup by 00:00 pm</span></div>
  <div class='typesd'>
    <label class='radio-inline'>
                <input type='radio' name='optradio' value='any' data-capaciteit='economy' checked>Any</label>
    <label class='radio-inline'>
                <input type='radio' name='optradio' value='box' data-capaciteit='economy'>Box</label>
    <label class='radio-inline'>
                <input type='radio' name='optradio' value='no box' data-capaciteit='economy'>No&nbsp;Box</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9foqat3k/3/

I am interested in reading `<span class='bb' id='economy_bike_amount' data-price='400'>Ksh 250</span>` when a radio button is clicked.

This line `var selectedPrice = $(this).closest('.bb').attr('data-price');` gives `undefined`. How would i read price without knowing the `id` of the span?

Comment: `.closest()` searches only in ancestors.

Comment: The price is static i guess.. check this on http://jsfiddle.net/53tq1nhk/

Comment: You should really use [.data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/) instead  `.data('price')`.  Your html does not intuitively allow us to know which radio button is associated to which element that has a `bb` class (because there are 3 elements with `bb`).

Comment: @Roy I cant introduce another class .

Comment: Use the id instead... `var selectedPrice = $('#economy_bike_amount').attr('data-price');`

Comment: Probably you best bet is `$(this).closest('.gbo').find('[data-price']).data('price')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.closest()` searches only in ancestors.

Instead, use this:

```
var selectedPrice = $(this).closest('.gbo').find('.transport_amount .bb').data('price');
```

```js
$('input:radio[name="optradio"]').change(function() {
  var selectedText = $(this).closest('.radio-inline').text();
  var selectedCapacity = $(this).data('capaciteit');
  var selectedPrice = $(this).closest('.gbo').find('.transport_amount .bb').data('price');
  console.log('Selected Text ', selectedText);
  console.log('Selected Capacity ', selectedCapacity);
  console.log('Selected Price ', selectedPrice);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='clearfix gbo' id='bike_economy' data-capaciteit='economy bike'>
  <div style='float: left;' class='bb'><img class='tic' src=''></div>
  <div style='float: left;' class='economy'>Economy</div>
  <div style='float: right;' class='infuhr'>
    <ion-icon class='ic' name='information-circle-outline' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='right' title='lorem ipsum'></ion-icon>
  </div>
  <div style='float: right;' class='bb transport_amount'><span class='bb' id='economy_bike_amount' data-price='400'>Ksh 250</span>
    <br/> <span class='pt' id='economy_bike_pt'>Pickup by 00:00 pm</span></div>
  <div class='typesd'>
    <label class='radio-inline'>
      <input type='radio' name='optradio' value='any' data-capaciteit='economy' checked>Any</label>
    <label class='radio-inline'>
      <input type='radio' name='optradio' value='box' data-capaciteit='economy'>Box</label>
    <label class='radio-inline'>
      <input type='radio' name='optradio' value='no box' data-capaciteit='economy'>No&nbsp;Box</label>
  </div>
</div>
```